# Parse INT Value from Website with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read an int variable from a web page. 
The web page includes a reading fom a sensor which wants to represent graphically in Java.

The content of the website "http://example.com/value.php?value=1" is only the value that I want to read.

For example the number "5".

Does anyone know a simple way to use this value as a variable in javascript?

Comment: The term you are looking is query string parameter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Well if the domain is a different domain, you have the same origin policy and CORS in your way.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1065332 - that shows how to read from the querystring. If you then need the value as a number have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp